# Save and call random variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, global-variables

I'm attempting to have my code create a number of random values, save those values, then allow me to manipulate those random values to create a number of profiles.

I'm currently having issues with both saving the numbers and with global and local values.

I have tried this so far:

```
import random

HP = random.randint(30,70)
Strength = random.randint (30,70)       

M_HP = random.randint(30,70)-10
M_Strength = random.randint (30,70)-10


def pilot_print():
    print ("Your pilot HP is " +str(HP))
    print ("Your pilot Strength is " +str(Strength))

def mech_print():
    print ("Your Mech HP is " +str(M_HP))
    print ("Your Mech Strength is " +str(M_Strength))
```

My issue is that I'm also attempting to put something like

```
def combine():
    HP+(M_HP/2) = C_HP
    Strength+(M_Strength/2) = C_Strength
```

My aim is to eventually create a game with character profiles generated randomly.

Would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Comment: You should be using a class. The following link uses creating a game character to introduce classes (so aka exactly what you're trying to do): http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=introduction_to_classes&lang=en

Comment: That is super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm attempting to have my code create a number of random values, save those values, then allow me to manipulate those random values to create a number of profiles

This is, in general, wrong approach. Right one is to have RNG internal state saved, so then after restoring it you'll get the same sequence of random numbers

Along the lines:

```
import random

state = random.getstate()
# save it, pickle it, ...

...

# restore state, unpickle it, ...
random.setstate(state)

# call to random.randint() will produce controllable sequence of numbers
```